# php getting array key column dynamically

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to dynamically get a specific data array by using a function (parsing an excel file, so for instance, I can grab the fourth column of the file as follows):

```
foreach ($obj->Worksheet->Table->Row as $row)
{
     $rows[] = (string)$row->Cell[4]->Data;
}
```

My problem is im trying to dynamically specify the "cell" to get and I dont know how to properly format it as I cant use $ within the [] apparently. So Im trying to do this and its not working:

```
$col = 4;
foreach ($obj->Worksheet->Table->Row as $row)
{
     $rows[] = (string)$row->Cell[$col]->Data;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use $ within the []?

Comment: Your syntax is fine and you certainly can use a variable (e.g. `$col`) for array access in that fashion. If your first code example works then your second should as well; they are equivalent. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: How do you identify that $ could not be used? It should work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was getting a trying to get property of non object error but I went back and played with it, the problem was when calling the function I was calling it like getColumn('3') instead of getColumn(3), the latter of which fixed the prob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression works, but if you have more complicated expressions use braces.

```
$rows[] = (string)$row->{Cell[$col]}->Data;
```